# I'm trying to run a powershell script from a batch file batch file but it appears to terminate the batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a PowerShell script that I'm trying to call in a batch file.  The Powershell script renews some credentials used by a subsequent .exe file, which expire after an hour.  I would then like to kill the PowerShell script, restart the PowerShell script, and restart the .exe.  Here's a simple example that reproduces my problem:

Test.bat

```
::@echo off
title Started at %time%
pause
Call CallPSWrapper.bat
::Never hits this pause
pause
echo call the .exe here
```

CallPSWrapper.bat:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy bypass -NoProfile -File .\MyPowerShell.ps1
```

MyPowerShell.ps1:

```
Write-Output "Waiting"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
```

I initially tried calling MyPowerShell.ps1 from test.bat, but tried changing it to being called by an intermediate batch file in the hope that PowerShell would only kill CallPSWrapper.bat.

Comment: What do you see when you do not hide the window?

Comment: Considering the 2 Bat files and the ps1 are on the same folder, if you remove `-WindowStyle hidden` it works just fine.

Comment: Try adding `exit` at the end of the .ps1

Comment: Removing the -WindowStyle hidden fixed it.  Do Compo or Santiago want to post an answer?